# Conversion of proposition to CNF

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If i have a proposition (B∧¬C∧¬T) ∨ (C∧¬B∧¬T) ∨ (T∧¬C∧¬B) how i convert it into CNF? I'm aware of the use of distributive law but I'm not quite good at it and the negation is confusing to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(B∧¬C∧¬T) ∨ (C∧¬B∧¬T) ∨ (T∧¬C∧¬B)$$

First commute the literals into an alphabetic ordering.

$$(B\wedge \neg C\wedge \neg T) ∨ (\neg B\wedge C\wedge \neg T) ∨ (\neg B\wedge \neg C\wedge T)$$

Now distribute.   The thing about the negations is that there will be a lot of cancellation.

$$\require{cancel}{\cancelto\top{(B\vee \neg B\vee \neg B)}\wedge \cancelto\top{(B\vee\neg B\vee \neg C)}\wedge \cancelto\top{(B\vee \neg B\vee T)}\wedge \cancelto\top{(B\vee C\vee\neg B)}\wedge \cancelto\top{(B\vee C\vee \neg C)}\wedge (B\vee C\vee T)\wedge ....}$$

Well, you get the idea.  There are just four terms which aren't tautological.

> $$(B\vee C\vee T)\wedge(B\vee \neg C\vee \neg T)\wedge(\neg B\vee C\vee\neg T)\wedge(\neg B\vee\neg C\vee T)$$

---

PS: You should recognise what this is.

> $B\oplus C\oplus T$ where $\oplus$ is "exclusive-or" (XOR)